# Authentication DB setting not working using mongoDB URI configuration

Tags: mongodb, eve

I am triyng to connect pyeve with a MongoDB Atlas replica set (https://cloud.mongodb.com/). I've connected successfully DB management tools from the same host, to make sure the deployment is working OK.

One particularity is that using Atlas, all users must authenticate against `auth` database, I cannot put my users in the application database, so I need to set `authSource` in `MONGO_URI`.

Now, when defining the `MONGO_URI` for the replica set, in `settings.py`, like this:

`MONGO_URI = mongodb://<USER>:<PASS>@my-shard-00-00-tlati.mongodb.net:27017,my-shard-00-01-tlati.mongodb.net:27017,my-shard-00-02-tlati.mongodb.net:27017/<MY_DB>?ssl=true&replicaSet=my-shard-0&authSource=admin`

The `authSource=admin` parameter seems to be ignored, (I've checked debugging pymongo's auth and the authentication source used is `None`).

`MONGO_AUTH_SOURCE` could be used to set the authorization database, but it has no effect since `MONGO_URI` is used in preference of the other configuration variables, according to eve's [documentation](http://python-eve.org/config.html#global-configuration).

Is this an issue or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the problem was that I was using version 0.4.1 for `flask-pymongo`. Updating it to version 0.5.1 fixed the problem.